# My element is out of screen and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: html, css, screen, element, bounds

I've recently made a simple navigation bar and it doesn't fit inside of my screen. I want it to be floated right. The problem here is that my navbarList is out of screen. It needs to be position: fixed, because otherwise it will move elements below. I really need to fix this quick.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zen41w7h/

```
        <div class="top">
            <div class="navbarOuter">
                <div class="hamborgor">≡</div>
                <div class="hamborgor2">×</div>
                <div class="navbarInner">
                    <ul class="navbarList">
                        <li><a href="Sub1.html" class="navbarButton">Sub1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Sub2.html" class="navbarButton">Sub2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Sub3.html" class="navbarButton">Sub3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&family=Dancing+Script:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Fraunces:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Lobster&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

* {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    margin: 0;
    
}

a {
    color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
    color: #555;
}

.top {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.navbarOuter {
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.hamborgor2 {
    font-size:55px;
    line-height: 43px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
} 

.navbarOuter:hover .hamborgor2 {
    display: block;
}

.navbarOuter:hover .hamborgor {
    display: none;
}

.hamborgor {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size:40px ;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: default;
    position: absolute;
}

.navbarInner {
    display: none;
}

.navbarList {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbarButton {
    background-color: palegreen;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 25px;
    display: block;
    width:100px;
    padding:12px 5px ;
}

.navbarOuter:hover .navbarInner {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to understand what you are doing but from what I see...No, you don't need `position: fixed`....just remove that and add absolute to ***navbarInner*** class:

```
.navbarInner {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Now it's still out of screen, but you still need to scroll to see it.

Comment: I literally dont see any scrollbar in my end though i checked it in Codepen...did you remove fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You use too much position fixed and too much fixed heights and widths everywhere... Just learn to use percentages in child elements as much as possible...
Anyways I just took the navBarInner out of navBarOuter since it was affecting it initially.. then removed bunch of fixed heights and widths and put the navBarInner to fixed position with right: 0; You can see the complete demo below

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&family=Dancing+Script:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Fraunces:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Lobster&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #555;
}

.top {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.navbarOuter {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamborgor {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
}

.hamborgor2 {
  font-size: 55px;
  line-height: 43px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.navbarOuter:hover .hamborgor2 {
  display: block;
}

.navbarOuter:hover .hamborgor {
  display: none;
}

.navbarList {
  padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.navbarButton {
  background-color: palegreen;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 12px 5px;
}

.navbarInner {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

.navbarInner:hover,
.navbarOuter:hover+.navbarInner {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="navbarOuter">
      <div class="hamborgor">≡</div>
      <div class="hamborgor2">×</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarInner">
      <ul class="navbarList">
        <li><a href="Sub1.html" class="navbarButton">Sub1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Sub2.html" class="navbarButton">Sub2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Sub3.html" class="navbarButton">Sub3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```